# kafka connect error in confluent 7.4.0 but not confluent 6.2.6

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

my broker version is 2.8.2. using cp-kafka-connect v6.2.6 for s3sink works fine. but if I change the docker image to cp-kafka-connect v7.4.0 I start getting errors like:

```
"Request joining group due to: rebalance failed due to 'The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group.' (MemberIdRequiredException) (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator)"
```

any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

```
The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group.
```

That error message seems to be related to changes in how Kafka handles consumer group membership. This change was introduced as part of [KIP-792](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=191336614#main), which was implemented in [Kafka 3.4](https://blogs.apache.org/kafka/entry/what-s-new-in-apache9). [Confluent Platform 7.4](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/release-notes/index.html), which you are using, includes Kafka 3.4, so this change would be present in that version of the platform.

KIP-792 expands the metadata each group member passes to the group leader in its `JoinGroup` subscription to include the highest stable generation that consumer was a part of. This information can be used by the partition assignor to determine whether the `ownedPartitions` claimed by a consumer are still owned and thus valid, and which consumer has the most recent claim to a given partition in case no one has a valid claim to it.

The error message you are seeing is generated when a consumer tries to join a group without a valid member id. This is part of the join group v4 protocol, and it is expected behavior: see [`tulios/kafkajs` issue 856](https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/issues/856) for, illustration. It seems like this error may not be a problem itself, but it is being surfaced due to changes in how Kafka Connect logs and handles such errors.

It is also worth noting that the Kafka community has been aware of the confusion caused by these error messages and has made changes to enhance the logging mechanism to make it less noisy and more informative in newer versions (as part of  [`KAFKA-10134`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/commit/16ec1793d53700623c9cb43e711f585aafd44dd4)).

But in short, the error message itself may not be indicative of a problem with your Kafka Connect setup. Instead, it may be more of an informational message about the protocol's functioning.

Comment: i think there is something else wrong as it is causing kafka connect pod to restart and there is node disconnected in the logs

Comment: @tooptoop4 I agree. I was just addressing the initial question, to explain where that error message is coming from. But here, aside from the `MemberIdRequiredException` and "`node disconnected`" messages, look for any other error messages in the Kafka Connect logs. These could provide additional clues as to what's causing the pod to restart.